# Function for if then condition not working because of apparently not specified variable

Tags: r, if-statement, syntax, conditional-statements

I've got a dataset of a pilotstudy with a test with 12 items. 
I've created the variable: test1_processed as follows, which gives me the amount of items the person could solve:

```
for(i in 1:length(test1)){
  data[,test1[i]] <- ifelse(data[,test1[i]]<=0, 1, data[,test1[i]])
}
describe(data[,test1])
data$test1_processed <- ifelse(apply(is.na(data[,test1]), 1, all),NA,rowSums(data[,test1],na.rm=TRUE))
```

Now I want to create a new variable, which simple enough codes a "1" if test_processed=12 (if all items were solved) or a "0" if not.

I tried it like this:

```
data$test1_complete <- ifelse(apply(is.na(data$test1_processed), 1, all),NA,1)
```

but R said, that dim(x) had to be positive.

So I checked the variable:

```
is.vector(data[,"test1_processed"])
[1] TRUE
is.numeric(data[,"test1_processed"])
[1] TRUE
```

Then I tried it like this:

```
data$test1_complete <- ifelse(apply(is.na(data[,test1_processed]), 1, all),NA,1)
```

but R said that the object test1_processed could not be found, even though it is a column in the data set.

If I tried it like this:

```
test1_processed <- ifelse(apply(is.na(data[,test1]), 1, all),NA,rowSums(data[,test1],na.rm=TRUE))
data$test1_complete <- ifelse(apply(is.na(data[,test1_processed]), 1, all),NA,1)
```

it said that undefined columns were selected.

Something like this:

```
data$test1_complete <- if(test1_processed>11) 1 else 0
only returned: Error in if (test1_processed > 11) 1 else 0 : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In if (test1_processed > 11) 1 else 0 :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I would be very glad, if somebody could help me out :)

Thanks!

Comment: I think that a small graphical example of how the data frame looks like after applying the first function  you described would be useful

Comment: @Carbo 
> dat_de$etc001_processed
 [1] NA NA NA NA 12 NA NA NA NA NA NA 12 NA  9 NA 12  7 NA 12 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[27] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 12 12 NA NA NA 12 NA NA NA NA 12 12 NA 12 NA 12 NA NA 12
[53] 12 NA 12 NA 12 NA NA 12

Does this help? My problem is that I've got a lot of NA's which should remain NA's, and the 12's should be scored as a 1 and the other values as 0. 
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you could try something like this is test1_processed is numeric and goes from 0 to 12

```
dt <- c(0, NA, 1, 11 , 12, NA)
dt <- as.data.frame(dt)
dt$allcorrect <- NA
dt$allcorrect[dt$dt > 11] <- 1
dt$allcorrect[dt$dt < 12] <- 0
```

something like this would work now

Comment: Do you have an idea how I could specify that not all values other than test1_processed >11 are zero, but that those that are NA remain NA?